# What is the best way to load data on listview without reloading all the adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i'm trying to implement a listview which load data dynamically.

the problem is that when i call the notifyDataSetChanged() function it reload all my adapter.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't reload your adapter, but refreshes the view.

You can implement add/remove/replace methods in your adapter and invoke notifiyDataSetChanged once the work is done, so the listview will be updated.